# vsftpd: 500 OOPS: config file not owned by correct user, or not a file

Tags: vsftpd

As it is in the topic the problem is with vsftpd. For some time i used it normally and everything worked good. But once i started vsftpd and it gave out the message:

> 500 OOPS: config file not owned by correct user, or not a file

After some searching i tried:

- to change the owner of the vsftpd.conf file by `sudo chown root vsftpd.conf`;
- to remove vsftpd and install again;
- to purge vsftpd and install again;
- to delete the content of the conf file and paste examples from internet.

Nothing helped, it did not work since.
It is Ubuntu 16.04

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Struggling with the same. file is owned by root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you still need this, but I had the same problem recently I Google around and found [This Page](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ftp-server-in-ubuntu/). The major difference I found was that I was trying to start the server by typing:

`# vsftpd`

Instead of:

`# systemctl start vsftpd`

in the terminal. I hope this helped.

Answer (score 3):

> $ vsftpd &
>   [1] 7685
>   500 OOPS: config file not owned by correct user, or not a file

The error is seen while running `vsftpd` as a background process.
I could not resolve the error, but I successfully ran the service.

Running the following command's(In Ubuntu) worked out for me:

```
$ sudo chown root:root /etc/vsftpd.conf
$ ls -lt  /etc/vsftpd.conf 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4429 Sep 12 00:26 /etc/vsftpd.conf
$ sudo service vsftpd start
$ sudo service vsftpd status
vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-09-12 00:47:46 IST; 4s ago
Process: 7882 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/vsftpd/empty (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 7883 (vsftpd)
Tasks: 1 (limit: 4531)
CGroup: /system.slice/vsftpd.service
        └─7883 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf
Sep 12 00:47:46 <Mysystemname>-G1 systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd FTP server...
Sep 12 00:47:46 <Mysystemname>-G1 systemd[1]: Started vsftpd FTP server.
```

Note: After this status, the FTP was successfully running on port 21.

```
$ nmap 127.0.0.1
  Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-09-12 00:50 IST
  Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
  Host is up (0.00012s latency).
  Not shown: 997 closed ports
  PORT    STATE SERVICE
  21/tcp  open  ftp
```

Answer (score 1):

## "Virtual" users

If you have, in your root:root-owned `/etc/vsftpd.conf`, something like

```
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/users
```

so that user `joe` uses further config in `/etc/vsftpd/users/joe`, well, then that directory and that file must **also** be owned by root and not world readable.

The difference is that in this case the 500 OOPS will only be shown **after a successful login** (i.e. once `vsftpd` has determined that you *are* user `joe`, and may then read the appropriate configuration file).

Answer (score 0):

This answer was a good indication to find the problem.
In my case next commands were the cause:

*#*** block access to shell in two steps ****


#1) assign the user's shell to false

usermod -s /bin/false


#2) add false to the shell list

echo /bin/false >> /etc/shells*

after commenting them out the server started.
So,first make sure that the server runs with your admin user then do things with other users as a ftp user.